# Link to another page and automaically toggle hidden div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page (...contacts.asp) with 4 buttons.

When a button is clicked it opens its associated `div` section and collapses the other 3 sections.  The logic for this works fine.

Now I want to link to this page from another one, but have the associated `div` section opened as directed by the `#tag` hash in the url link http....contacts.asp#Sales.

My code is as follows, I added the `if` statement hoping that would work but it does not.

```
function showhide(id) {
    document.getElementById('Corporate').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Outlets').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Sales').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Service').style.display = "none";

    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}

if ( location.hash != 0 && location.hash == '#Sales' ){
    document.getElementById('Sales').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: You may use `localStorage` to send the values to another page. When load the other you can retrieve the value and do your thing. See this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Your condition should be working.  I assume it's not a case issue?  Did you confirm the url included `#Sales` with an uppercase S?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant code probably is executed to early.

More precisely when this code:

```
if ( location.hash != 0 && location.hash == '#Sales' ) {
document.getElementById('Sales').style.display = "block";
}
```

is executed, the '#Sales' DOM-Element maybe doesn't exist yet, because the DOM hasn't been loaded completely. So nothing will happen by executing this.

This means the code has to be executed after the DOM is loaded. To do this there is e.g. an 'DOMContentLoaded' event. (You could also use the 'onload' event.)

So as solution you should write the code inside that event handler:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // the if statement
});
```